# NodeJs POST Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, express, http, post

I am trying to run a simple app that just sends the current location to a server. Here is my setup:

```
//Client

if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  console.log("Geolocation available");
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    const lat = position.coords.latitude;
    const lon = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("latitude-span").textContent = lat;
    document.getElementById("longitude-span").textContent = lon;

    const data = {
      lat,
      lon
    };

    console.log(data);
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    fetch("/api", options);
  });
} else {
  console.log("Geolocation not vailable available");
}


//Server

const express = require( "express" );

const cors = require( "cors" );

const app = express();

app.use( cors() );

app.use( express.static( "public" ) );
app.use( express.json( {
  limit: "1mb"
} ) );

app.post( "/api", cors(), ( request, response ) => {
  console.log( request );
  response.send()
} );

app.listen( 5500, function () {
  console.log( "listening at 5500" );
} );
```

As you can see, I am using express in a NodeJs project, I am just starting this back end js adventure and I can't figure this out. I always get this error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/api net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(anonymous) @ scripts.js:23`

Can somebody help me? I've looked up for similar question and I can't seem to find them.

Comment: Possible CORS issue, try passing the credentials flag in `fetch`

Comment: Can you link me an example?

Comment: I don't really know what you are talking about.

Comment: link for the CORS:
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Maybe you are referring to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials. But I don't know how to include in the `fetch`

Comment: Your express route doesn't send any response, even thouth that might not be the real problem ... you should try adding a `res.end()` or `res.send()` after your `console.log(request)`.

Comment: I believe my problem is in the Client because none of the changes I do inside the server shows any progress.

Comment: Even if I stop the server, the error is still shown.